# Javascript if statements not working properly on html page

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wrote a script a couple of days ago that would switch the css stylesheet for my page depending upon the time of day. It seemed to work fine until I realized that after it went through the script once, it would just stop.

For Example. When I first implemented the script, it would use one style sheet duing the day, then a different in the evening, then a 3rd one during sunset, and finally once at night.  It would do this the first time around. But then after the 4th switch it won't switch again unless I re-implement the script. It just stays on the stylesheet that was switch to at the bottom of the script Since I'm new to javascript I have no clue why it's doing this.

I have used this same javascript function to control pictures and other things and they seem to work flawlessly. Here is the code.

```
<!--CSS Stylesheet Switch Code--->

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function getStylesheet() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
      if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 17) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/vice.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (17 <= currentTime && currentTime < 19) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/evening.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (19 <= currentTime && currentTime < 21) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/dusk.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      else  {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/nighttime.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
}

getStylesheet();
-->
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after **it** went through the script once"?  Are you talking about a single logged in user who refreshes the page every few minutes?  Or does this work only for the first day after it's deployed?  At the moment I can't imagine in what situations this should fail, since each time the page is loaded, the script should be evaluated completely distinct from previous attempts.  More information on your tests would be helpful.

Comment: “unless I re-implement the script” — how do you mean “re-implement”? What do you do to get it working again?

Comment: Try to clear cache and then renew page. May be there are problems with cache

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't word this correctly. What i'm saying is that after the last stylesheet is switched to. the 'nighttime.css'. I never switches back and stays on that stylesheet.

Comment: By 're-implement' I simply mean, I take the javascript out and save the html file. Then I go back and paste the code back in and it works for some reason afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Javascript If..Else If..If Statement like below:-

```
if (7 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/vice.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  else if (17 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 19) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/evening.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  else if (19 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 21) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/dusk.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  else  {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/files/nighttime.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Even if one of the first two statements are correct, one of the last two will always execute. Change your ifs to else ifs, or use a switch.